# Could un-install sharepoint designer from sharepoint servers affect the dll, patches, updates that are being used by sharepoint service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, windows-server, windows-server-2008-r2

I have two sharepoint farms; Live & Test. both have the following software specification.

- sharepoint enterprise server 2013, with SP1.
- installed inside windows server 2008 R2.

now when i build our Live & Test servers , i have install sharepoint designer 2013.but lately i have read many articles which mentioned that it is recommended not to install any office or other application other than sharepoint inside sharepoint servers. so now i am planning to un-install sharepoint designer .. now on our Test server, i followed these steps:-

- Control Panel.
- Uninstall a program.
- select sharepoint designer 2013.
- click on remove.

and the SP designer got uninstalled correctly.but before doing the same steps on on live server can any one advice on this point, if un-installing SPD can cause any harm to sharepoint serivces:-

Since both SharePoint service 2013 & SharePoint Designer 2013 are within the office suite,, so they might share some patches , updates and .dll files.. so my concern if i un-install sharepoint designer inside the sharepoint server could this remove .dll or patches which is related to sharepoint ? or un-installing sharepoint designer will not affect sharepoint and will not conflict with the .dlls , patches related to sharepoint??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the SharePoint Designer on one my of SharePoint 2016 dev farm. after that i uninstall it from the server and test the functionality. Everything is working as expected.

So, as per my test, I think you can uninstall the SPD without effecting SharePoint install.

I recommend you to uninstall from test farm then do the testing.

Comment: i did so inside my SP 2013 test machine and seems everything went well,, then i did the same process on live.. the only thing i noted is that before un-installing SPD there were many windows updates targeting office products such as powerpoint, word, etc although  i do not have these installed inside sharepoint server (seems thoese wll be installed incase i have SPD).. but after un-installing the SPD all these updates were removed .. but i assume that these updates are not related to sharepoint, and will not affect sharepoint..

Comment: You are right, most probably they are related to SPD

Comment: now at the end i am in two situations; to keep SPD installed inside sharepoint servers , to eliminate the risk of un-installing it, OR to un-install SPD with the risk that un-installing it might cause problems to sharepoint.. so i decide to go with the second approach (Un-install SPD) and seems everything went well so far...

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Designer from the server will have no effect. It's like uninstalling Word or Excel... they're not related to SharePoint patches or assemblies (dll's).

Comment: thanks for ur reply.but they are within the same office suite is this correct? now the reason i want to un-install SPD, since i read that having SPD inside sharepoint server can cause some patches which are targeting SPD to cause some dll which is being used by sharepoint to get updates ,, so that why it is not recommended to install any office product (other than sharepoint) inside sharepoint servers. but if the two products (sharepoint and sharepoint designer) are not related and do not share any thing,, then there is not any reason to un-install the designer ?? is this valid point ?

Comment: Designer isn't part of the office suite. I don't know why it's not recommended. Do you have the link to the article you're citing?

Comment: i am looking into the article i read